# where is the tooltip gone for misspelled words in ios 10

Tags: keyboard, ios, spellcheck

**update:** I have check spelling on under settings for both keyboards.

Please try and not misunderstand this question. **I'm NOT** talking about the white background word suggestions white typing.

I believe before iOS 10 if a **word had a red squiggly** if you tapped it you would get a **black tooltip** with a suggestion.

Can this be somehow turned on again? I don't see anything on the web even mentioning it, it's like noone noticed it! (The black tooltip does show up still but **only in the case** you type a word and hit backspace.)

I can add screenshots if you guys need it.

Like I've mentioned in the [comment to the first answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/261363/where-is-the-tooltip-gone-for-misspelled-words-in-ios-10/261371#comment327311_261371), I have check spelling on.

Answer (score 1):

The feature you're talking about is called spell check, and is different to the automatic spelling correction that occurs when you type.

It still exists in iOS 10.

To make sure that it is enabled:

**Settings > General > Keyboard > Slide "Check Spelling to on"**

If it is already enabled, I would recommend disabling it, restarting, re-enabling it and then restarting again to be sure.

Lastly, make sure you are using the default Apple keyboard by going

**Settings > General > Keyboard  > Keyboards > Ensure "English UK" or "S" is checked.**

Comment: I thought so before posting ...I have "check spelling" to **on** under settings. I use two keyboards; English and German, above the on/off button group where check spelling is, it says "English and German" so it applies to both keyboards.